# The clothes color is not shown correctly when imported in blender

Tags: texturing

I created a cloth from the mesh i downloaded.

I used marvelous designer to create the clothes.

Please have a look at the picture. This is the Viewport shading solid mode

[image]

And this is the display render preview

[image]

Added the properties of the clothes

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please point me out the reason for this. I'm still a beginner in blender and i don't have a formal education about animation or blender. I just search for tutorials. Thank you

I also attached the clothes

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k__szcb0fndUQs6ykomf-DQvdoxs_v3Q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello, could you post a screenshot of the node network of the material used in the cape ? Also it seems the "metallic" value for the skin is set to 1 when it should be at 0

Comment: @Gorgious good day. I updated the question and also attached the clothes file